# Coupon code definition and usage restriction

Tags: coupon, user, restriction

Please Suggest a method to restrict the coupon code for 1 time only, even if the coupon codes are bulk generated using the Manage Coupon Codes functionality. All individual codes needed to be restricted for 1-time use only for guests or registered users. (logged in or not).

Also suggest a method for restricting coupons only for App users, like in the case of providing coupons for 1st time App users.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cart rule you can select "Specific coupon" and you can fill in the number of uses per coupon. If you want to use autogenerated coupons you need to check the checkbox "Use Auto Generation"

[image]